# QueryBuilder: Sum values of a pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm new on Laravel & Eloquent. I have Users, Products and Votes tables on my DB. Users can vote (0 to 5) on products, so it is a "many to many" relationship, with the Votes table acting like a pivot:

- Users: id, name, email, password
- Products: id, name, model, brand
- Votes: user_id, product_id, vote

I mapped this schema like this:

```
// User model:
public function product_votes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'votes')->withPivot('vote');
}

// Product model:
public function product_votes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'votes')->withPivot('vote');
}
```

So John can vote 5 on product X and 0 on product Y. Bob can vote 2 on product X, 3 on product Y, and so on...

I'm trying to query all products, with the sum of votes of each one of them. Something like:

```
SELECT p.*, (SUM(v.vote) / COUNT(*)) as votes FROM products p INNER JOIN votes v on v.product_id = p.id GROUP BY p.id
```

How can I do that with QueryBuilder? My mapping is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do the trick:

```
Product::select('products.*', DB::raw('SUM(vote)/COUNT(*) as votes'))
->join('votes', 'votes.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
->groupBy('products.id')
->get();
```

You can see the query that will be run by calling **toSql()** instead of **get()**.

Comment: That's it!. Thanks for the toSql() tip too.